# Probability of having $1$ or more tails in flipping a coin four times.

Tags: probability, statistics

> If you flip a coin four times, letting $x$ be the number of tails, then find the probability of having $1$ or more tails. Then find the expected mean.

Answer (score 2):

We assume the coin is fair and that tosses are independent of each other.

The probability of one or more heads is one minus the probability of no heads:

$$P(\ge1\text{ tails})=1-P(0\text{ tails})=1-\tfrac{1}{16}=\tfrac{15}{16}$$

The distribution is binomial with $n=4,p=0.5$, so the mean is $np=(4)(0.5)=2$.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the binomial distribution. The probability mass function for the number of successes $k$ out of $n$ trials of a binary experiment (tails or heads) in which the probability of success is $p$ is as follows:

$$ f(k;n,p) = {n\choose k}p^k(1 - p)^{n - k} $$

An easy way to compute P(at least one) is to compute 1 - P(none).  So you can do the following taking $n = 4$ coin tosses, $k = 0$ tails, and $p = 0.5$ as the probability of tails on any given flip.

$$P(\text{at least one tails}) = 1 - P(\text{no tails}) =  1 - {4\choose0}0.5^0(1 - 0.5)^4 = 1 - 0.5^4 = 0.9375 $$

The mean of any binomial distribution is $np$.  So you have $0.5*4 = 2$ fore your expectation.